# wordpress functions doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

I have a form that grabs data from users and save it as a blog post.

The form action goes to this page:

```
wp-content/plugins/formplugin/savepost.php
```

But in that page when I try to save post by `wp_insert_post($args)`, this error happens:

```
"Call to undefined function wp_insert_post() in D:\EasyPHP-5.4.0RC4\www\wp2\wp-content\plugins\formplugin\savepost.php on line 18".
```

Is there something missing?

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])){

    $args=array(
        'post_name'      => $_POST['postname'],
        'post_title'     => $_POST['postname'],
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_excerpt'   => $_POST['postdesc']
    );
    wp_insert_post($args);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Include WordPress in external files:**

It looks like you are using an external file outside the scope of WordPress. Even if the file is in the plugins folder, doesn't mean WordPress necessarily knows about it.

You can include WordPress to your external file adding this:

```
<?php 
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', FALSE );
require_once( '/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

at the top of your file. The `wp-blog-header.php` should be located in the WordPress root folder.

**Alternative:**

But since you are using WordPress, why not construct a [pretty url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) and use a [hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) to intercept the form posting, instead of pointing to an external file?

**Things to consider:**

You should consider using [filter_input](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) instead of `$_POST`.

I would also recommend using the [WordPress nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces).

It's a good rule to *validate* and *sanitize* all user input. [Here's](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Input_Validation) a good starting point on that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the error message makes the error very clear.

The message `Call to undefined function` means that in the file you are going to, the function doesn't exist.

So within the `savepost.php` page there is no function called `wp_insert_post()`.

You'll need to add this in or you could instead send the data by loading in `wpdb` and using that instead.

Read more here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score -1):

Your function wp_insert_post() ...it say's it doesn't exits or it can't be reached.